# Can you reset Fallout Shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

Can you do a hard reset in fallout shelter as in starting the game from the beginning again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every time you start a new vault, you start with the vault door and elevators alone, you have to go through the tutorials again, and you get the easy objectives that reward lunchboxes again.

If you want to reset a vault, delete it from the vault list in the main menu, and start another vault on top of its save slot. To reset your game, you can delete all of your vaults and start them over.